# How to mail to a particular email id using my gmail credentials from desktop application

Tags: sendmail, email, google-api, google-buzz

I am just developing an a desktop application for Twitter, Buzz and facebook. Google Buzz has not released their whole api to post buzz, but today I came to know that to create a new Buzz just mail to buzz@gmail.com with subject as Buzz content you want to create.

Now I got stuck that how to mail to buzz@gmail.com from my gmail id using destop application which I am developing. Is there any kind of google webservice or api is available to do the task?

Thanks,
GG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP) to send mail through Gmail.
First, you will need to enable either POP or IMAP (or both) for the Gmail account in settings.

You can then connect to SMTP.Gmail.com on port 587 using SSL.

For more detailed instructions, please tell us what language you're writing.

Comment: I am writing Desktop app in Action Script 3.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a [Post to Google Buzz API](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/buttons_and_gadgets.html) that is pretty easy to use.  You simply construct the URI like this:

`http://www.google.com/buzz/post?message={your_message}&url={your_url}`

There's also a JavaScript API that generates the buttons for you:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post"
  class="google-buzz-button" title="Google Buzz"
  data-message="{your_message}"
  data-url="{your_url}"
  data-locale="en"
  data-button-style="normal-count"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/buzz/api/button.js">
</script>
```

There is also documentation for the [full REST API](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html).